# Occam's factor and the VC dimension

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, bayesian, vc-theory

I was watching this lecture by Prof. Dr. Philipp Hennig (Probabilistic ML) and when he reached this formula which is the type two maximum log likelihood I had the following question:
[image: type two maximum log likelihood]

The Occam's razor/factor is capturing the complexity of the model, even though the word 'complexity' isn't trivial to me since it can mean many things. Is the word 'complexity' implying the VC dimension of the model space?

Comment: can you link the lecture?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb0K_S5JJU4&list=PL05umP7R6ij1tHaOFY96m5uX3J21a6yNd&index=9&pp=iAQB